# Creating a Livestock Purchase & Sales App php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, pdo

I'm currently building an inventory system designed for livestock purchases and sales where a user can input cattle details such as description, color, weight, etc. Using JQuery, a percentage of the weight is subtracted(7%), then the remainder is multiplied by the price and the total cost is saved to the database along with all the other input data. The results are then displayed to another page where they can be seen and sold from.

I added new input boxes to the sale page with new weight, new price and new total cost. The new weight is to follow the same formula (-7%), multiply by new price and store these new items into the same row/record in database and redirect to a page where all data (including new weight/new price/new total can be seen). I am using UPDATE with PDO and I am not getting any errors but new data is not being recorded.

Can/Should I include a form in echo?
How to submit that form, given that I have to use $row. id in the submit/href field?

If I can achieve this, the next step is to add a #profit readonly input below new total input that would subtract old cost from new cost. Is this possible with JQuery?

Purchase page, Sell page, Update page and JQuery code below in that order.

Edit***
I have added the result.php page at the very bottom.

The question would be, is placing input fields inside a php echo correct?
Or how would I add new data to that auto-generated row that has to be selected by id?
Last question, would the last piece in JQuery work? I don't know how JQuery would retrieve the old cost in the same row.

Thank you.

```
<?php include 'includes/header.html' ; ?>


<body>

<form action="result.php" method="POST">

        <label for="desc">Description</label>
            <input type="text" id="desc" name="desc" placeholder="No horns, mad cow, Herford, etc.." required>
        <label for="desc">Color</label>
            <input type="text" id="color" name="color" placeholder="Gray, red, black & white, etc.." >
        <label for="desc">Weight</label>
            <span><input type="number" id="kg" name="kg" placeholder="345kg, 455kg, 660kg, etc.." required>kg</span>
        <label for="desc">Price p/kg</label>
            <span>$<input type="number" id="precio" name="precio" placeholder="$12.50, $22, $30, etc.." required></span>
        <label for="desc">Ear Tag</label>
            <input type="text" id="arete" name="arete" placeholder="00453E, 2111RG, etc.." >
            <br/><br/>


        <label for="costo">Total Cost</label>
            <input type="number" name="costo" id="costo" readonly />        
                <br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" id="comprar" name="submit" value="Make purchase">   

</form>


</body>
```

Sell page below

```
  <?php include 'includes/header.html'; ?>

  <?php require_once ('db/conn.php');



  try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  }catch(PDOException $e) {
     die('Error');
  }

  $tableheader = false;
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `compras` ORDER BY `id` ASC";
  $sth = $conn->prepare($query);

  if(!$sth->execute()) {
     die('Error');
  }

  echo "<h1 id='title'>Cattle</h1><table>";


  while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     if($tableheader == false) {
     echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
           echo "<th id='valor'>{$key}</th>";
        }
     echo '</tr>';
        $tableheader = true;
     }

     echo "<tr>";
     foreach($row as $value) {
           echo "<td id='valor'>{$value}</td>";
     }
     /* Add Delete Button with css id to target with CSS and Query */
     /*echo "<td><button id='boton1'>Vender</button></td>" * Initial button for Vender */

           echo "<td>
                  <label>New Weight</label>
                    <input type='number' name='npeso' id='npeso' placeholder='new weight'>
                  <label>New Price p/kg</label>
                    <input type='number' name='nprecio' id='nprecio' placeholder='new price'>
                  <label>Total Sell Price</label>
                    <input type='number' name='ncosto' id='costo' readonly />                                     
                 </td>";

           echo "<td id='vender1'>
                    <button id='boton1'>
                       <a href='update.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "'>Sell</a>
                    </button>
                 </td>";
     echo "</tr>";
     }
  echo "</table><br/>";
  ?>

  <?php include 'includes/footer.html'; ?>
```

Update Page

```
    <?php require_once ('db/conn.php');


    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


        $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
        $sqlu = " UPDATE `compras` SET `npeso`= '$npeso', `nprecio`= '$nprecio', `ncosto`= '$ncosto' WHERE id=" . $id;

        // use exec() because no results are returned
        $conn->exec($sqlu);
        header( "Location: exito.php" );
        /*echo "New record created successfully";*/
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        }

    $conn = null;

    ?>
```

JQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    /* Space for Declaring Global Variables and creating total profit calculation*/
    costo1 = parseFloat('#costo').val() || 0;
    costo2 = parseFloat('#ncosto').val() || 0;

    /* JQuery for Cattle price calculation on comprar.php page */

            $('#kg, #precio').keyup(function(){
                var peso = parseFloat($('#kg').val()) || 0;
                var precio = parseFloat($('#precio').val()) || 0;
                var deweyo = (peso * .07);
                var neto = (peso - deweyo);

            $('#costo').val( neto * precio);   
            });


    /* JQuery for Cattle price calculation on modal */

        $('#npeso, #nprecio').keyup(function(){
          var peso = parseFloat($('#npeso').val()) || 0;
          var precio = parseFloat($('#nprecio').val()) || 0;
          var deweyo = (peso * .07);
          var neto = (peso - deweyo);
          var costo2 = parseFloat($('#ncosto').val()) || 0;

          $('#ncosto').val( neto * precio);
        });

    /* Calculation for total profit */
        $(costo2, costo1).keyup(function(){

          $('#profit').val(costo2 - costo1);

        });

    });
```

Result.php

```
            <?php include 'includes/header.html'; ?>

        <?php require_once ('db/conn.php');



        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `compras` (`descri`, `color`,`peso`, `precio`,`arete`, `costo`)
            VALUES ('$description', '$color', '$kg', '$precio', '$arete', '$costo')";
            // use exec() because no results are returned
            $conn->exec($sql);
            header( "Location: success.php" );
            /*echo "New record created successfully";*/
            }
        catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
            }

        $conn = null;
        ?>





        <?php include 'includes/footer.html'; ?>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Also your form runs a script called `result.php` but you dont show us that script. I assume that is where the database UPDATE code would llive

Comment: I have added the page in question. The first issue is adding new data to the same row using pdo. No errors are given but data isn't sent and I know it's in the way the input is sent but don't know the correct way.                  Second question is subtracting old cost from new cost in same record. I can't get JQuery to select the value from an auto generated record, don't know how.

Comment: For me, this is far too much information & code. I'd suggest to minify your question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Learn [ask] and [mcve]. It's only a 5 minute read and will save you hours. We want to help, but we need some context. Please [edit] your question to reflect it. What else did you try? What are you asking? Make it clear.